# Adjust column width in Nattable - show complete column name when selected

Tags: nattable

I need to display complete column header name, when column is selected, it means increase column width. And reset width when column is deselected. I did not find example in `nattable_examples.exe`. Is there some built in feature?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no built-in feature that would support automatic increase/decrease of column widths on selection. You will need to implement some [selection listener](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_500_Layers/_505_Selection/_5053_SelectionEventsExample.java) and then do an auto-resize on the selected column by using the `AutoResizeColumnsCommand`.

But I don't think we have an event on deselect, so I am not sure how you want to reduce the column width again.